# My app requires passwords be checked *locally* - how can I avoid security issues?

Tags: passwords

I have an app in which there's a Main Account Owner who has a completely secure server-side-checked password, hashed and salted, which is great. No worries there.

But each account also has a list of 'employees' and the full employee table is regularly downloaded for storage locally on the app devices. The full table, including the password field, has to be available *offline* so it has to be downloaded and stored, and the password has to be checked rapidly.

Is it better practice to store a "PIN" rather than a password in this situation? Is there any use in encrypting these passwords? What sort of encryption can I do that would be extremely fast and easy to implement across languages?

This particular password/pin, keep in mind, doesn't actually give access to a lot of app features, this simply allows them to log in and log out, so realistically the lack of security isn't disastrous -- there's not much someone could do maliciously even if they had one of these passwords.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking from the perspective of the person who is building this app?  Or someone who is using this app and is concerned about their security?

Comment: Since you already state that an attacker could not really do much harm even when knowing the passwords it is unclear what security issues you mean when asking *"... how can I avoid security issues?"* The only one I could think of if a user reuses the same credentials somewhere else - which you have no control over in your application.

Comment: @ConorMancone building

Comment: @SteffenUllrich well I'm aware that one of the dangers of discoverable passwords can also be that the users *other* accounts accross the internet can be compromised. If my password on one insecure site is Heather, and my password on other secure sites is also Heather, just getting access to my password from one site grants you access to my accounts anywhere. Which is why I thought maybe the concept of a PIN in this context is more appropriate - if I learn your PIN on one site, there's potentially more limited damage I can do elsewhere.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich This particular security risk is also lessened by the fact that these "employee" accounts aren't connected to an email.

Comment: Another idea is to just make sure that the users of the app know that these passwords are insecure and should be simple, one-word passwords that they don't use elsewhere. Which is I suppose similar to what a PIN accomplishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have two choices:

1. Perform proper password security and send down hashes for the local system to verify
2. Use a "PIN" rather than a password to minimize harm if credentials are stolen.

To recap what you are asking, the obvious issue is that having to send down the credentials in some form increases the risks of credentials being stolen.  With password reuse a never-ending problem, passing people's passwords around for local validation is a danger to your users more than anything else.

Encryption doesn't really help a ton (or maybe depending on your security concerns) because regardless of what hoops you make the app jump through, the app still has to be able to verify the passwords offline, which means that there is a way to get back the plain text passwords.

**Hashing**

Probably the most secure way to use actual passwords is to just follow standard protocol and use a secure password hashing algorithm.  Obviously you therefore **don't** want a fast aglorithm, but I can't imagine the phone will be so much slower at hashing as to cause painful UI problems.  Obviously you'll have to reproduce your hashing algorithm on your phone - presumably that won't be too much of a problem for standard hashing algorithms.

The hashing provides a basic layer of protection against the passwords getting stolen in transit or from the phone.  Obviously though it won't protect weak passwords against brute forcing.  However, if these passwords aren't connected to user details otherwise (for instance email addresses), then that is less of an issue - every password I ever used could be splashed publicly across the internet but it wouldn't matter if my email address isn't connected to them.  If you can make sure that the passwords are not connected in any way to **any** personal information, then there is less of a concern.

**PINs**

The other option would be to use a PIN, as you mention, and make it definitively a PIN - numbers only.  This will keep people from reusing their password.  However, it won't keep people from reusing their ATM PIN number, so I would still keep these credentials far from any personal information.

In short, if all you have is a password or PIN then it is no longer really a password - it is just a unique identifier assigned to a user.  This is much less dangerous to have stolen (or at least, only dangerous to your app and what that unique ID allows a malicious user to do).  Therefore the best option is really just to make sure that these local passwords are never connected (or connectable) to actual user information.

Comment: A lot of what you said is what I've gathered from my own thoughts, conversations with developers I know and reading. I'm thinking of going with a 5- or 6-digit pin

Answer (score 2):

Besides user-selected password and user-selected PIN, a third strategy is a system-generated password. This can offer a good degree of security and, because it's generated, guarantees it won't be a reuse of something the user already uses elsewhere. Being you don't need loads of security, you could use a 2- or 3-word passphrase. An adjective-noun format is easy.

If you get lists of 100 adjectives and 1000 nouns (google for the word lists), that will give you 100,000 possible phrases. That's as strong as a 5-digit PIN. The PINs will be things like `purple meerkat` and `abstract house`. You can add an adverb at the start to make the password stronger. For example, adding only 30 adverbs would yield phrases like `subtly purple meerkat` and `very abstract house` and gives you 3,000,000 possible phrases - that's better than a 6-digit PIN.